# How to get all bond angles within a structure, using pymatgen?

Tags: python, pymatgen

So, using pymatgen, I have a structure object. What I want to do is get all of the bond angles within the structure. I could loop over every atom to get all bond angles, but this would include every atom, regardless of how far apart they are, which of course is a problem.

Now, I can find the neighbors of each central atom using the "get_neighbors" function, however, I'm not sure where to go from here, especially because the "get_angle" function takes integer values and not atomic site objects.

Below is the code I have thus far:

```
import pymatgen as mg
import numpy as np


s = mg.Structure.from_file('POSCAR')

atoms = s.atomic_numbers

van = [x for x in atoms if x == 23]
length = len(van)
nb = ['NONE']*length

x = 0

while x < length:

    nb[x] = s.get_neighbors(s[x],2.4)
    x += 1
```

So I have an array of the neighbors and I know which atom they correspond too, now I just need to get the angles for all neighboring atoms.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

So, I've figured out a way of doing this. I actually converted each neighboring atom into their Cartesian coordinates. Then, I subtracted the coordinates of the central atom to which the neighboring atoms are attached. Lastly, I found the angles by calculating the dot product of each two vectors divided by the product of their magnitudes, then taking the arc cosine of these values. The code which I used is below. This may not be the most elegant way of doing things, but it does get the job done. If anyone has improvements, feel free to comment.

```
import random
import itertools as iter
import pymatgen as mg
import numpy as np
import math


def all_angles(POSCAR,amin,amax):

    s = mg.Structure.from_file(POSCAR)

    atoms = s.atomic_numbers

    van = [x for x in atoms if x == 23]
    length = len(van)
    nb = ['NONE']*length

    x = 0
    n = 0

    while x < length:

        nb[x] = s.get_neighbors(s[x],2.4)
        x += 1

    w = 100
    h = len(van)
    oxygen = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

    x = 0
    y = 0

    while x < len(nb):

        y = 0
        n = 0

        while y < len(nb[x]):

            oxygen[x][n] = (nb[x][y][0]).coords
            n += 1
            y += 1

        x += 1

    x = 0

    while x < len(oxygen):
        oxygen[x] = [n for n in oxygen[x] if not isinstance(n,int)]
        x += 1

    van = [x for x in range(0,len(van))]

    x = 0
    while x < len(van):
        van[x] = s[van[x]].coords
        x += 1

    van = [np.array(x) for x in van]

    x = 0
    while x < len(van):

        oxygen[x] = [np.subtract(oxygen[x][y],van[x]) for y in range(0,len(oxygen[x]))]
        x += 1

    combo = [[0 for x in range(0,1000)] for y in range(0,len(van))]

    r = 0

    while r < len(van):
        x = 0
        for subset in iter.combinations(oxygen[r],2):
            combo[r][x] = subset
            x += 1
        r += 1

    x = 0
    while x < len(combo):
        combo[x] = [c for c in combo[x] if c != 0]
        x += 1


    angles =  [[0 for x in range(0,1000)] for y in range(0,len(van))]

    x = 0

    while x < len(combo):

        group = combo[x]

        y = 0

        while y < len(group):
            angles[x][y] = math.degrees(math.acos(np.dot(group[y][0],group[y][1])/(np.linalg.norm(group[y][0])*np.linalg.norm(group[y][1]))))
            y += 1

        angles[x] = [round(n,3) for n in angles[x] if n != 0 and n > amin and n < amax]

        x += 1

    angles = np.concatenate(angles,axis=0)    

    return angles
```